# Request: How to set user agent for every request?

Tags: node.js, npm

Using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) is it possible to set the user agent for every request?

Currently I have to set it at the time of making the request:

```
request.post(url, { form: form, headers: { 'User-Agent': ua }}, function(err, resp, body) {
    // Do some stuff
})
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a request method with your own defaults:

```
var customHeaderRequest = request.defaults({
    headers: {'User-Agent': ua}
})
```

Then use it:

```
customHeaderRequest.post(url)
```

see https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestdefaultsoptions