# Call External URL from API

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, express

I getting a captchas page when I want to bring some JSON data from URL when I Call it from my API

I try to bring data from array of JSON, but when I request it from my API I Just get an enpoint of Captchas, I just want some data, like openPrice, highPrice, price, and lowPrice. But I just get a captchas form and not the array of JSON

```js
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var sql = require("mssql");
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var useragent = require("express-useragent");
var bloomberg = `https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/quote/CUR/USDMXN%3ACUR?locale=en/`;

//GET API TEST EXCHANGE
app.get("/api/exchange", function(req, res){
  request({
    url: bloomberg,
    json: false
  }, function(err, resu, body){
    if(!err && resu.statusCode === 200){
      res.send(body);
    }
  });
});
```

I just want to bring 3 data

```js
{ openPrice: 19.1159, price: 19.1014, lowPrice: 19.0585, highPrice: 19.129, }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tested on my localhost:

- That one is not working. It returns no data.

```
curl https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/quote/CUR/USDMXN%3ACUR?locale=en/
```

- That one works:

```
curl https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/quote/CUR/USDMXN%3ACUR?locale=en/ -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36
```

Set User-Agent Header to:

`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36"`

or other User-Agent which is recognized as a browser. Probably they check if http-client is a bot or sth else - idk bloomberg API

The topic might be useful for you:

[Request: How to set user agent for every request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073527/request-how-to-set-user-agent-for-every-request)